# DoJo AMD any realworld applications out there?

Tags: javascript, dojo, amd

I am new to DoJo and  Iam experienced with other JS tools such as AngularJS NodeJA, Knockout etc. But I am not able to find any full application such as ToDo or Contacts etc in the AMD or DoJo 1.7 or later. All the one exist or pre 1.7 version and I cannot use them in my project.

I know this is a well seasoned and mature product, so may be my search is not right I been searching using DoJo AMD 1.7 Ajax Application and all possible combinations.

I see Modern Hello World, seriously,  I know how to do that now. How do I get beyond that?

Appreciate if anyone could point me to a useful DoJo app tutorial using AMD.

Thank you

Comment: First result in google for "dojo todo": http://todomvc.com/examples/dojo/ Demos: http://demos.dojotoolkit.org/demos/

Answer (score 1):

Several useful resource here:

To do simple app:
http://todomvc.com/examples/dojo/

Custom widget tutorial, show how to set up a simple app like card name:
https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/recipes/custom_widget/

Learn by looking at how dojo team write their test cases, so you can see how they initiate and use their widget (select Browse tests > [popular]):

http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/dojo-2017-02-01/

Link to DOJO API so you can read details for each dojo module.

http://dojotoolkit.org/api/

Dojo Boilerplate a set of files to help you rapidly get up and running/ It illustrates some basic best practices when working with Dojo (it is very useful IMO).
https://github.com/csnover/dojo-boilerplate

I hope it helps as a starting point.

Comment: Please consider adding a comment when down-voting. Thanks for your help :)